# What is the sum of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ N + \frac N2 + \frac N3 + \frac N4 +\frac N5 + \cdots + 1 $$

I don't want the series to be solved .

Please provide Any hint or idea would be enough to solve it by my own ?

Comment: Google for "Harmonic series"

Comment: Not sure what sort of answer you are hoping for.  You get $N\times \left(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac 1i\right)=NH_N$.  Where $H_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ [Harmonic Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: Is the secon $\frac N2$ supposed to be $\frac N5$?

Answer (score 3):

Factor out the $n$ to get:

$$N(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{N})$$

You can rewrite this as:

$$Nh_N$$

Where $h_n$ is the nth harmonic number but there isn't really a "nice" closed form for $h_n$.

If you want an approximation (treat $h_n$ as a function that is defined for all real $n$) :

$$h_{n}-h_{n-1}=\sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}-\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{n}=\frac{h_n-h_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)} \approx \frac{d}{dn} h_n$$

Hence:

$$h_n \approx \int \frac{1}{n} dn$$

$$h_n \approx \ln |n|+c$$

Let $c$ give you the best approximation as $n \to \infty$:

$$c:=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(h_n-\ln |n| \right)$$

This constant is known as the Euler-Mascheroni constant and is often denoted $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

$$N + \frac{N}{2} + \frac{N}{3}+ \frac{N}{4} + \frac{N}{5} +  ........ + 1 =$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{N}{k}=N\cdot\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k}=N\cdot\sum_{k=1}^Nk^{-1}= N\cdot H_n$$

Where $H_n$ is the n-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's following pretty much the same road, but here's my solution using integrals:

$$N\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1k=N\int_0^1\frac{t^N-1}{t-1}dt$$